# Check how many consecutive days a user has used an app

Tags: ios, swift, analytics, watchos-2

I've already seen other questions asking about how many times the app has been opened. I want to send a local notification when the user uses the app for 31 **consecutive** days.

Would this be a *NSUserDefaults* discovery method or would I need to use an analytics API?

Comment: This question is more about registering push notifications than it is about keeping track of the install date - might help to rename your question.

Comment: Well I'm not going to be able to send anything if I don't know the data e.g. how long user has used the app for. One leads to the other. Question is about what the title says. I go on to further ask if I should use analytics to get the data. So no the question is not more about push notifications.

Comment: Assuming a user has used the app for 30 consecutive days. 31st day the user opens the app making it 31 days in a row. So should the app send a notification while the app is in foreground on the 31st time .

Comment: I don't think so because it might be the 80th time they open the app in 31 days. I'm not looking for open counts. I'm looking for day counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UserDefault`. In appdelegate's `didFinishLaunch` method check for days count

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     
    let kLastUsed = "LastUsedTime"
    let kDaysCount = "DaysCount"
    let currentDateTimeInterval = Int(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    var storedDaysCount:Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: kDaysCount)
    if storedDaysCount >= 31 {
        //show pushNotifications
    }
    else {
        let lastDateTimeInterval = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: kLastUsed)
    
        let diff = currentDateTimeInterval - lastDateTimeInterval
        if diff > 86400 && diff < 172800 {
            //next day. increase day count by one
            storedDaysCount = storedDaysCount + 1
            UserDefaults.standard.set(storedDaysCount, forKey: kDaysCount)
        }
        else if diff > 86400 {
            //not next day. reset counter to 1
            UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: kDaysCount)
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentDateTimeInterval, forKey: kLastUsed)
    }
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. You confirmed what I wrote in my question. I thought that this could be done using `UserDefaults`.  Question. It's impossible to wait for 31 days for testing :) Could I test for minutes instead? Or would it work setting my Macbook or simulator clock ahead 31 days?

Comment: change the current date of the device. you won't need to wait for 31 days. And while testing if you find any case which I miss then pls tell me.

Comment: `storedDaysCount = storedDaysCount + 1` is the part that checks for consecutive days?

Comment: no. condition `if diff> 3600 && diff < 7200` check for days. where 3600 is seconds in one days.

Comment: Isn't 3600 seconds just one hour? I like to use "60 * 60 * 24" to avoid any mix ups.

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal has this answear worked for you ? i think that there is a problem with 3600.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on Hitesh's awesome answer to make it more suitable for realtime testing.

You cannot change the date in the simulator settings like you can on a real device. And if you change the date on your real device you might get some Apple server-Xcode syncing issues and Xcode will ask you to register your device in the Developer Portal again.

*Test on a real device using the current time because the UserDefaults needs the date and store from the real device.

To test for minutes or seconds just change all the `Ints` to `Doubles` and change the condition to something finer like **if storedDaysCount >= 0.0000000015**.

```
let kLastUsed = "LastUsedTime"
let kDaysCount = "DaysCount"
let currentDateTimeInterval = Double(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)

var storedDaysCount:Double = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: kDaysCount)
    if storedDaysCount >= 0.000000000015 {

        print("storedDaysCount = \(storedDaysCount)")
```

Comment: I can confirm this. I couldn't change the date on the iPhone sim. I tested on my device.